# site loading for invalid URL's and redirection error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

currently I am using this htaccess access,but the site still loads for invalid url, it doesn't goto 404.
ex: http://www.couponcoder.in/babyoye.com -->works and main content

http://www.couponcoder.in/babyo ----> invalid url, it displays homepage

and site loads for both slash and without slash, I just want it to redirect non-slash

www.couponcoder.in/babyoye.com/

www.couponcoder.in/babyoye.com

can someone help out with this?

Options +Indexes

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?couponcoder\.in$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1couponcoder.in%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^admin$ Admin/index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't read if you want to have the non-slash version or if you want to redirect the non-slash version to the slashed one. I'm assuming you want the former.

```
...

#remove slash, and redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Gerben, I need non slash version and I want invalid url to show 404 page,but now its loading to home page.see here http://www.couponcoder.in/babyoye.com -->works....

http://www.couponcoder.in/babyo ----> invalid url, it displays homepage,it should show 404

Comment: You need to change the php for the 404 part.